# Android Firebase: signInWithCustomToken takes a very long time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Attempting to sign into Firebase using a custom token on Android takes roughly 30 seconds to complete on average. It's not a network issue as the call to my server to get the custom token returns in a very short amount of time. This is using the latest 10.0.1 version for each Firebase library. Here is the relevant code:

```
String customToken = //retrieved from server

firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(customToken).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

        //30 seconds later, task is successful


    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d("error", "failed to sign in with custom token " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
});
```

I know that the custom token is valid because the operation eventually succeeds, but not after hanging for 30 or more seconds. Needless to say, that kind of performance is unacceptable in a production app.

Comment: [Turn on debug logging](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/ed3236d26e60ab3b4b855f89f20df517) and include that here. It'll help to include all the relevant code, sample data, debug logging, and version info so we can fully understand the problem. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Kato a bit late to the party but I have the same issue although my delay is 5-10 seconds.  I turned on the debug logging but that provides no insight because the database logging only starts after the sign in completes

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I'm using the most recent version of firebase-auth:18.1.0. Does anyone know of any solutions to this?